# beautiful soup vs selenium vs urllib

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib3, python-requests-html

I am working on a web automation project. I need to be able to pull pages, assess data, and be able to interact with the page (e.g. login, enter values, and post to the site.) As a derivative of the logins, I think I will need something that will allow me to remain logged in given a credential (e.g. store the credential or cookies.)

I've already used UrlLib & Requests libraries to pull files and the pages themselves.

I am trying to decide on the best Python library for the task.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

thank you!

Comment: this question may get downvoted as it's kind of open-ended/opinion-based. But essentially the best library to use is dependent on your needs.  If you can reliably recreate the HTTP requests being used to authenticate logins and speed is important, urllib/requests for making those HTTP requests and beautifulsoup for parsing the HTML responses would be best.  Otherwise, Selenium is where you'll have the most luck.  Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @n1c9 : when you say:
'If you can reliably recreate the HTTP requests being used to authenticate logins'

Do you mean like the url mail.yahoo.com (and then login) or with the cookie (/auth) already baked into the url request?

Comment: The URL.  Essentially, logging in will require you to use a either a requests.Session() object (to maintain the same session, cookies, etc. over a number of HTTP requests) or use Selenium to achieve the same result.  If you don't know a lot about HTTP authentication and speed isn't a huge concern (i.e. you won't benefit from a 500 millisecond speed improvement) I would recommend Selenium as it handles a lot of that stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks man.

Is it similarly simple to use as urllib? Is the installation complex?

Comment: Installation should just be a simple `pip install selenium` - tough to really compare it to urllib fairly because they perform different functions, but in my experience it's pretty user-friendly where urllib is a little more no-frills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@n1c9

> If you can reliably recreate the HTTP requests being used to authenticate logins and speed is important, urllib/requests for making those HTTP requests and beautifulsoup for parsing the HTML responses would be best. Otherwise, Selenium is where you'll have the most luck. Let me know if you want more details.

Looks like Selenium is the right answer.